# Active Directory SYSVOL not synchronized across domain controllers

Tags: active-directory, sysvol

I have two domain controllers and I noticed that their SYSVOL shares were inconsistent when a random sample of client machines started to fail at executing their logon scripts (they were executing an obsolete version of this particular script).

The random sample was caused by the GPO referring to \\[Domain name]\sysvol... rather than \\[server name]\ , therefore the client machine was at the mercy of our nameserver to get the correct logon scripts.

1. What can I do to get the sysvol directories replicated properly again?
2. What events can cause this to break, or what can I do to prevent this from happening in the future?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check time synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm, I would be checking your AD replication if i where you as this should not be out of sync.  replmon and dcdiag are what I would look at for a start.

Indeed FRS is what is used to replicate the sysvol folder in my experience these things tend to go hand in hand.

In saying that if its a server 2008 domain you will probably be using DFS-R not FRS so would look at that.

suppose its one of them that could do with some more information instead of trying to assume.

Comment: Hi Harry, as per the FAQ, please don't include signature blocks in your answers - this is what your profile page is for.

Answer (score 1):

SYSVOL replication is separate from AD replication. SYSVOL is replicated using the File Replication service (FRS).  There's some very good TechNet articles for troubleshooting FRS issues, e.g.: 

[Troubleshooting File Replication Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727056.aspx).